# How to fix NextJS occurred prerendering page when deploy problem

Tags: firebase, next.js, deployment, web-applications, vercel

[image]

My project
https://github.com/kiattichai-haruansri/Portfoliowebsite

I don't know what error I re-checked syntax but not have error

I deploy on vercel using Next React JS Tailwind Firebase

error said at /admin/cert-edit/[id]

I tested but not having any problem and was using npm run build

some code in /admin/cert-edit/[id]

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { getCertById } from '@/pages/api/getCert';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link';
import { doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db, storage } from '@/confic/firebase'
import {
    ref,
    uploadBytesResumable,
    getDownloadURL,
} from "firebase/storage";

const Cert = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = router.query;

    const [certData, setCertData] = useState(null);
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

    const certRef = doc(db, "Cert", id);

    const handleFileChange = (e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const cert = await getCertById(id);
            if (cert) {
                setCertData(cert);
                setTitle(cert.title);
                setContent(cert.content);
            }
        }

        fetchData();
    }, [id]);

    if (!certData) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    const item = certData;

    const handleSave = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (file === null) {
            console.log("No file selected");
            updateDoc(certRef, {
                title: title,
                content: content,
                pic_url: item.pic_url,
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Document successfully update!");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
            return;
        }
    
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `cert/${file.name}`);
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
    
        uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
                const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
                setProgress(progress);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            () => {
                getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
                    updateDoc(certRef, {
                        title: title,
                        content: content,
                        pic_url: url,
                    })
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log("Document successfully update!");
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
                        });
                });
            }
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className='flex h-full xl:h-[calc(100vh_-_64px)] w-full items-center justify-center'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSave} className='flex flex-col p-4 w-11/12  h-4/5 border border-black 
                ...
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Cert;
```